# Name of conjectures similar to Goldbach conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

Consider the following """easier""" conjectures:

**C1**. every sum of two semiprimes $n = pq + rs$, $p,q,r,s$ primes, can be expressed as $n = (a + b)/2$; with $a,b$ primes.

**C2**. every number $p(q + r)$, $p,q,r$ primes (sum of two squarefree semiprimes that share a factor), can be expressed as $p(q + r) = (a + b)/2$; with $a,b$ primes.

Do they have an official name/literature?

Comment: You might be interested in closely related [Chen's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chen%27s_theorem): it states that all large enough even numbers are either a sum of two primes, or a prime and a semiprime.

Comment: @Wojowu : thanks ... though I realize that it's a "sea of unknowness" ... just discovered "are there infinite primes q = 2p+1, p prime?" (safe primes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe either has a name in the literature.

Also, I don't know how much easier these conjectures would be. They don't seem to have any useful structure for the problem to take advantage of. C1 is almost surely equivalent to the Goldbach conjecture itself: probably every number greater than 33 (resp., 82) is the sum of two semiprimes (resp., squarefree semiprimes). See [A072931](https://oeis.org/A072931), [A072966](https://oeis.org/A072966), and [A329481](https://oeis.org/A329481).